# How to overcome current drop in circuit with high inductance value?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, ltspice

I have a very simple circuit that uses a switch to switch between a resistive loop and inductive + resistive loop.
Whenever I switch from resistive load to inductive load, the current of the source current measured over the R2 drops to almost 19A.

How can I make the current stay stable even when I switch the switch?

The current drop happens when I turn off the switch as shown on picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the current stay stable even when I switch the switch?

Try removing the diode across the current source.

If you need the diode then please don't expect miracles with inductors - they fight against a changing current and, when the switch is activated, the inductor current will have fallen to zero amps thus, when opening the switch (to allow current to try and pass through the inductor) you can't expect all the 100 amps to instantly pass through it - the inductor will resist and that is what you see.

This is a fundamental property of inductor - they produce a counter emf proportional to the rate of change of current. This means if you expect an infinitely fast change in current, the inductor produces an infinitely high back emf to counter that change.

Comment: The diode I used it as my current source has a voltage limit of 2.6V. I do understand the inductor inertia against current change. I was just thinking if it could be possible to keep the inductor and the same time having no influence on the current curve

Comment: It’s basic physics, an inductor produces a counter voltage proportional to rate of change of current. It’s a fundamental physical thing carved in stone just after the Big Bang. If it didn’t do this, there would be no radio waves, no light, nothing.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I was just trying to manipulate the behavior of the current in my benefits.

Comment: Maybe if you explained what you are trying to make it might help find some workaround.

Comment: Actually, this circuit is a simulation of real behavior of source Current that is used to inject a current to similar circuit I have drawn. The switch is real and whenever I turn it on and off the source current drops as you see and I was trying to overcome this drop of current and make it constant. So the inductance exist in the circuit which is a stray inductance